# I want to put a button inside datagrid's column tag in flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml, itemrenderer

I need to put a button in one of the columns of datagrid tag and the column's value should appear on the buttons label. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Why not flex4 and spark DataGrid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In flex 3, use the tag `mx:itemRenderer`:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myDataGrid" dataProvider="{myDP}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="field">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:Button label="{data.field}"/>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

In flex 4, use spark dataGrid and the `s:itemRenderer` tag:

```
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{myDP}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Price">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <s:Button label="{data.Price}"/>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>    
            </s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```